# How to bind a list of objects to ListBox in GWT?

Tags: gwt

I want to bind my services to ListBox but I can't bind it.
//Service class

```
 public class Service {
    private String serviceName;

    public Service(String serviceName) {

        this.serviceName = serviceName;
    }

    public String getServiceName() {
        return serviceName;
    }

    public void setServiceName(String serviceName) {
        this.serviceName = serviceName;
    }

    }
```

//   SignUpBean class

```
  public class SignUpBean {
        private List<Service> services;

    public List<Service> getServices() {
        return services;
    }

    public void setServices(List<Service> services) {
        this.services = services;
    }
}
```

The following is my Main Editor

```
public class SignUpEditor extends SimplePanelimplements Editor<SignUpBean> {

    public ListBox services;
public void SignUpEditor (){
services.addItem("Service1");
    services.addItem("Service2");
setWidget(services);
}
}
```

I am not getting any error but I think I have to use `ListEditor` or `CompositeEditor`. But i don't know about it. Can anyone suggest how to bind `Service` to `ListBox`

Answer (score 0):

ListBox suppose to be a LeafValueEditor. Conceptually we don't edit the list in the ListBox. Rather We select a value from the list which will be displayed in the selection. So, ListBox holds only one value and thus ListBox must be leaf value Editor.

Currently there is no GWT support to directly bind the list to ListBox. We have to write an adapter which extends ListEditor ( Refer HasDataEditor class for more detail ). This approach is strange.

Simple approach is to write an adapter which implements LeafValueEditor< List < String > >. In adapter's setValue method we should iterate over the list and call listBox.addItem for each value in the list.

I don't recommend either approaches simply because ListBox's `LIST is NON EDITABLE` and only `VALUE is EDITABLE`. I recommend doing addItems manually without using Editors.

**UPDATED** : HasDataAdapter is an example ListEditor. Refer that implementation. You may get some idea.